# error: binding reference of type 'unsigned long' to value of type 'const unsigned long' drops 'const' qualifier

Tags: c++, class

I defined two functions for my `Solver` class as follows:

solver.h

```
class Solver: public DSPOMDP {
     friend class State;
protected:
        std::vector<State*> states_;
        std::vector<OBS_TYPE> obs_;
   
private:
      unsigned long histObs = 0;
      const unsigned BitsPerValue = 3;
      const unsigned Mask = (1u << BitsPerValue) - 1;

public:
      Solver();
      static Solver* current_;
      void store(unsigned long &n, unsigned x) const;
      unsigned get_max(unsigned long n) const;
      double ObsProb(OBS_TYPE obs, const State& state, ACT_TYPE action) const;
};
```

solver.cpp

```
using namespace std;

Solver* Solver::current_ = NULL;
State::State() {
}

State::State(int _state_id) {
    state_id = _state_id;
}

State::~State() {
}

Solver::Solver() {
    current_ = this;
}

void Solver::store(unsigned long &n, unsigned x) const{

    n = (n << BitsPerValue) | x;
}

unsigned Solver::get_max(unsigned long n) const{

    unsigned m = 0;
    for ( ; n; n >>= BitsPerValue) 
        if ((n & Mask) > m) 
           m = n & Mask;
    return m;
}
double Solver::ObsProb(OBS_TYPE obs, const State& state,
    ACT_TYPE action) const {
      store(histObs,obs_[state.state_id]);
      return obs == get_max(histObs);
}
```

I am getting these errors:

```
src/solver.cpp:334:19: error: binding reference of type 'unsigned long' to value of type 'const unsigned long' drops 'const' qualifier
            store(histObs,obs_[state.state_id]);
                  ^~~~~~~
src/solver.cpp:48:44: note: passing argument to parameter 'n' here
void Solver::store(unsigned long &n, unsigned x) const{
                                           ^
src/solver.cpp:358:13: error: binding reference of type 'unsigned long' to value of type 'const unsigned long' drops 'const' qualifier
      store(histObs,obs_[state.state_id]);
            ^~~~~~~
src/solver.cpp:48:44: note: passing argument to parameter 'n' here
void Solver::store(unsigned long &n, unsigned x) const{
                                           ^
```

I have been trying to define the variable `histObs` inside the class and its methods which keep track all the changes made in the `obs_`vector. I don't know how it should be implemented in a right and efficient way?!! How can I fix these errors?

Comment: By fixing your code. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It appears you are trying to modify a member variable of a const object.  Don't do that.

Comment: Your code does not match your error messages.

Comment: @TanveerBadar What about now? I added more lines of code which is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `unsigned long` to `const unsigned long&`, that is legal. But you can't assign const to non-const reference, because you can later change const object. You can change its parameter with `const unsigned long&` or just don't pass constants

Comment: can you be more specific for which parameter it is happening?

Comment: @Dalek `void store(unsigned long &n, unsigned x) const;` I am about this. In first parameter it takes `unsigned long&` you cant assign `const unsigned long`

Comment: I modified my question a bit and if maybe you address that then it might solve my problem.

Comment: I defined `histObs` as `unsigned long histObs = 0;` which is not a `const` value, right?

Comment: @Darek notice at the end of `void store(unsigned long &n, unsigned x) const;` you wrote const and you want to pass  `histObs` member to it. That const promises this method won't change anything in class object, but you want to pass his member as `unsigned long &n` (which is not const). And that breaks promise